# WebSphere not launching completely?

Tags: websphere, application-server

We use WebSphere for the message queues only. We have an application that is using them in a single node environment. I have it installed exactly how its installed and configured in our other single node environments, but for some reason, the page functionality is not working and I am assuming its because of this error?

[ERROR][Authenticator] Unable to find JVM server name under property: serverDomain. System is not properly configured for cluster environment.

Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have to reconfigure the custom properties, take a look here - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/xrun_jvm.html#com.ibm.config.allow.set.session.timeout you might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using port 8879... which is clustered env port. I switched it over to 8880 in websphere and the applications database and it works fine now.